# Excel: alternative to long IF statement

Tags: excel

Trying to calculate the total amount based on different discount factors throughout the term. For example, if a base price is $1,000/month, that will be for months 1 – 24, then $500/month 25-48 and $250/month 49 and after. I think I can do this with IF statements but is there a better way to compute this calculation in Excel?

[image]

```
=IF(B2<=$E$2,A2*B2,IF(AND(B2>=$D$3,B2<=$E$3),(24*A2*$F$2)+(B2-$E$2)*(A2*$F$3),IF(B2>=D4,(24*A2*F2)+(24*A2*$F$3)+(B2-48)*(A2*F4))))
```

Comment: What kind of output do you want?

Comment: The total amount, which in this example is $36,250. With the IF statement =IF(B2<=$E$2,A2*B2,IF(AND(B2>=$D$3,B2<=$E$3),(24*A2*$F$2)+(B2-$E$2)*(A2*$F$3),IF(B2>=D4,(24*A2*F2)+(24*A2*$F$3)+(B2-48)*(A2*F4)))) But wanted to see if there is an easier way to do this computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your table as shown below, and use the following formula:

```
=A2*VLOOKUP(B2,$D$2:$F$4,2)+A2*(B2-VLOOKUP(B2,$D$2:$F$4,1))*VLOOKUP(B2,$D$2:$F$4,3)
```

There is no test done for maximum months.  You can add that as an `IF` if necessary.

This method allows for a lot of flexibility in altering the terms.  It is also useful in calculating things like income taxes and other stuff for which there is this kind of "tiering"

**EDIT:** The formula for the `Base` column:

```
E2: 0
E3: =E2+(D3-D2)*F2
```

and fill down from E3 to the bottom of the table

[image]

Comment: This is really neat. I was just wondering if you could include the formula in column E for working out the Base figures?

Comment: @TomSharpe See the Edit

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for the formula, it works very well but adding another layer of complexity, how can I cap the monthly discount rate to be no lower than $300 a month? In this example the monthly amount is as follow: 
0-24: $1,000
25-48: $500
49-after: $250 (how could I cap this to be at $300?)

Comment: @user6437637 Just change the discount rate in the lower right corner.  You might want to use a formula to determine that rate, dependent on the monthly amount.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I used a formula to calculate the rate and works well when I have a single amount to calculate. How can I do this for multiple entries at the same time, where there are multiple different amounts to calculate?

Comment: @user6437637 Without more specifics, it is hard to advise further.  I suggest you pose this as a new question,starting with this solution that works for all except this last piece, and show examples, what you have tried, what you want, and what you are getting for results.